# Does there exist a convex function which is not strictly differentiable almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

It is known that:

(i) There exists a locally Lipschitz function on an Euclidean finite-dimensional space  which is almost everywhere (almost everywhere means "except a set with Lebesgues measure zero") Frechet differentiable but is not almost everywhere strictly differentiable.

(ii) Any convex function on an Euclidean finite-dimensional space is strictly differentiable except a set of the first category.

(iii) There exists a set of the first category on $\mathbb R$, the complement of which has Lebesgues measure zero.

I have a question: Does there exist a convex function on an Euclidean finite-dimensional space which is not almost everywhere strictly differentiable?

Note that for a convex function, strictly differentiable at a point means that its subdifferential of convex analysis reduces to a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Wang  posted an answer that every continuous convex function on a finite dimensional Euclidean space is almost everywhere strictly differentiable and provided some references and I would like to thank him for the very useful answer.  The arguments for the above result can be found in the paper
*Borwein, J. M.; Moors, W. B., Essentially smooth Lipschitz functions. J. Funct. Anal. 149 (1997), no. 2, 305–351*:

1. On separable Banach spaces, the continuous convex functions are strictly differentiable everywhere except on a Haar-null set (page 312)
2. In finite dimensions, the Haar-nulls sets coincide with the Lebesgue null sets (page 322).

For other facts on subdifferential, see *S. X. Wang, Fine and pathological properties of subdifferentials* (thesis)

Comment: On can find in Qi, L., The maximal normal operator space and integration of subdifferentials of nonconvex functions, Nonlinear Anal. 13 (1989), 1003-1012.